# Map loading on chrome is very slow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good evening, excuse-me for my bad english.
I've a speed problem when loading any page (with a map) from my website like www.viaggiodaunavita.com/monte-pilatus--ch-.html with Chrome and not with Explorer or other browser.
I'm using 3.30 API version loaded with my personal key.
Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.30&key=AIzaSyDSmNy1SXiamqr6lRmkTzpf0TauOR9yDHk&callback=initMap">`

Why do you write initMap when your function is called initialize?

Comment: Thanks, this is a mistake but the problem remains also installing Chrome Canary